# z-index with after pseudo

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I am building a navigation bar which will contain a hamburger menu button. I have created a container to hold the button, however I wanted to give it's container a slanted look with the pseudo after class, which I have done.

However the pseudo class appears in front of its parent, and I want for it to appear behind the parent div. If I set the z-index of the pseudo class to -1 it ends up sitting behind the navbarContainer div, and changing the parent z-index to anything higher doesn't make a differnce.

I've tried playing about with the z-index to change the stacking order of the different components but can't get it to work so was hoping someone could help me out :)

Hope that makes sense! If not I have created a jsfiddle which demonstrates my issues: https://jsfiddle.net/x2w3u48e/
Basically I am trying to get the green pseudo element behind the red parent div, but not behind the blue nav bar menu.

[Example picture of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THF4l.png)

(fyi I have made the pseudo class green for ease for now, but it will be the same red color as its parent. Eventually the parent will contain a hamburger menu button)

HTML:

```
<div id="navbarWrapper">
    <div id="navbarMenuLeft">
        <div id="hamburgerContainer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbarWrapper{
        background-color: #001E49;
        width: 100%;
        height: 68px;
        float: left;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #000; 
    }

    #navbarMenuLeft{
        float: left;
        height: 68px;
        padding: 0px;  
    }



    #hamburgerContainer{
        height: 68px;
        width: 70px;
        background-color: #E2003B;
        position: relative;
        left: 40px;
    }


    /*gives the container a skewed look*/
    #hamburgerContainer:before{
        background-color: green;
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 40%;
        position: relative;
        right: 18px;
        transform: skewX(-15deg);
        transform-origin: 100%;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/61mt7usu/

The summary is that pseudo-elements tend to act like children of the elements they are attached to, so it's hard to hide them behind the parent. One solution which I implemented in the fiddle is to just swap the parent and child and adjust margins accordingly, so that the parent element is the lowest layer.

Note since the parent now has a skew, the psuedo element needs to have the opposite skew to appear straight.

The relevant CSS change:

```
#hamburgerContainer {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  height: 68px;
  width: 28px;
  position: relative;
  left: 22px;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
  transform-origin: 100%;
}

/*gives the container a skewed look*/
#hamburgerContainer:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 68px;
  width: 70px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #E2003B;
  left: 18px;
  transform: skewX(15deg);
  transform-origin: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Ah of course! Thanks for your help Karin, seems to do the trick!